# Objective-C objects & blocks

Tags: objective-c, object, block

I tried and I have successfully allocated a block into and id variable. Is a block an obj-c object? Why we use NULL instead of nil? (If it is an object)

Answer (score 2):

A block can be used as an object in an Objective-C context (that is to say, a pure C or C++ program compiled with GCC or LLVM can also use blocks, but they cannot be used as objects since neither language understands Objective-C in a meaningful way.)

Generally, you should use `nil` for objects, `Nil` for `Class`es, and `NULL` for other pointers. I don't know who you're seeing using `NULL` instead of `nil` for blocks, but that's not what I'd do in an Objective-C context (as before, in a C or C++ context, `nil` and `Nil` are not available without bringing in Objective-C runtime headers, so there I'd be using `NULL`.)

Comment: Such as? I've always used `nil` myself.

Comment: NULL, nil, 0 - all the same thing in Objective-C.

Comment: @Lluís: Good sample code that works with Objective-C objects will never use `NULL` for them (though it will use them for non-object null values.)

Comment: @rmaddy: It's a language convention to distinguish between `NULL` and `nil` as above.

Answer (score 2):

A nice feature of C blocks is that they can behave like rudimentary Obj-C objects.  You can cast a block to `id`; you can send a block Obj-C messages like 'copy', 'retain', 'release', 'autorelease'; you can stuff a block into an NSArray or NSDictionary.  But when it comes time to execute the block, you must cast it back to its original type.

NULL, nil, Nil, and 0 are just different words for zero.  Choosing one over the other is merely documentation for your fellow programmers; it makes to difference to the compiler.

By convention, `NULL` represents a null C pointer, and `nil` represents a null Obj-C object.  Since a block is both of those things, your fellow programmers will not ridicule you for choosing either NULL or nil to represent a null block.  And your compiler certainly won't care.